# How to convert message received by Swift socket communication to String type

Tags: swift

I want to do TCP communication using a library called [SwiftSocket](https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket).

Below is the sample code of SwiftSocket.

```
func echoService(client: TCPClient) {
    print("Newclient from:\(client.address)[\(client.port)]")
    var d = client.read(1024*10)
    client.send(data: d!)
    client.close()
}

func testServer() {
    let server = TCPServer(address: "127.0.0.1", port: 8080)
    switch server.listen() {
      case .success:
        while true {
            if var client = server.accept() {
                echoService(client: client)
            } else {
                print("accept error")
            }
        }
      case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

I want to convert the received message to String in the third line of the above code

```
var d = client.read(1024*10)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
  if let string = String(bytes: d, encoding: .utf8)
  {
      print(string)
  } else
  {
      print("not a valid UTF-8 sequence")
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I got a following error `Value of optional type '[Byte]?' (aka 'Optional<Array<UInt8>>') must be unwrapped to a value of type '[Byte]' (aka 'Array<UInt8>')`